# C# How to calculate time until someone is 18 based on their DOB

Tags: c#

Let's say I need to have a license suspended until the driver is 18 years old.  All I have is their DOB.  I cannot add the time to their specific DOB because this will go for many drivers with different DOB.  Here is the line of code that is already created but this is adding 18 years to their DOB which is not what I want.

```
        data.EndDate = data.Driver.DateOfBirth.GetValueOrDefault().AddYears(18);
```

Comment: `this is adding 18 years to their DOB which is not what I want` - why not? To me that sounds exactly like what you're looking for.

Comment: I believe you want to subtract, not add 18 years. Just replace the 18 with -18.

Comment: @MirekE: No, that would be "what was the date 18 years before they were born" which isn't terribly useful.

Comment: @MirekE You turn 18 years old 18 years before you are born?

Comment: No. I would calculate a limiting date (DateTime.Now().AddYears(-18)) and then compare with actual birth date. Please note that the OP is saying he can't add the dates to specific DOB...

Comment: @MirekE That tells you when they would need to be born in order to be 18, not when they turn 18 or how long it will be until they turn 18.

Comment: @AdamV I think I was assuming this was adding 18 years to the current DateTime but it's not.  It is in fact adding 18 years to the DOB which is exactly what I want.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @Servy Looks like we have different understanding of the original question. Mine was that he needs to determine eligibility at the current time. Perhaps I was wrong. Got misguided by the statement that the data.EndDate = data.Driver.DateOfBirth.GetValueOrDefault().AddYears(18); is not what he wants...

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the amount of time remaining in a `TimeSpan`, you can just subtract two `DateTime`s.

```
TimeSpan timeLeft = data.Driver.DateOfBirth.Value.AddYears(18) 
    - DateTime.Now;
```

Also, I am using `Value` instead of `GetValueOrDefault()`, since you probably never want to use a default value for date of birth.